# Google chart / Spreedcheat : Specify tab in sheet

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am looking for a way to specify which row from the sheet I want to use in order to draw the chart.

I have two different tables in my Google sheet and want to draw two different charts. Do I need to seperate the data with two different sheets, or tabs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are a couple options...

**1)**

the tables can exist on the same sheet / tab...

you can use the `setQuery` method to select specific columns and / or rows

e.g. you could use column `A` to identify the table number,
then select only the rows from that table...

```
query.setQuery('select B,C where A = 1');
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lmmpJs2Bz3EfQWExB4KXq_uJWoLlq1PMCahy6w4ipcE/gviz/tq?gid=942634171');

    query.setQuery('select B,C where A = 1');

    query.send(function (response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
        console.log('Error: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }

      var datatable = response.getDataTable();
      var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
      chart.draw(datatable);
    });
  },
  packages:['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

---

**2)**

you can specify which sheet to use in the query,
and even a specific range of cells...

to specify, use the following parameters on the spreadsheet url...

```
sheet=Sheet1

range=B1:C10
```

e.g.

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/.../gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet1&range=B1:C10`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var queryStr = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lmmpJs2Bz3EfQWExB4KXq_uJWoLlq1PMCahy6w4ipcE/gviz/tq?gid=942634171';

    // specify sheet / tab
    queryStr += '&sheet=Sheet1';

    // specify range of cells
    queryStr += '&range=B1:C10';

    var query = new google.visualization.Query(queryStr);

    query.send(function (response) {
      if (response.isError()) {
        console.log('Error: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }

      var datatable = response.getDataTable();
      var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
      chart.draw(datatable);
    });
  },
  packages:['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps -- note: found a random spreadsheet to use for the above examples, not sure who's it is...